# 502 bad gateway: Nginx, gunicorn, Django

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Here is my `nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 0.0.0.0;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /myproject;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock;
        }
    }

}
```

And my project have this structure:

[image: This is my Directory]

This is my `gunicorn.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/root/myproject/myproject
ExecStart=/root/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`error.log`

```
2022/04/13 12:45:30 [crit] 20474#20474: *8 connect() to unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.81.234.10, server: 0.0.0.0, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock:/", host: "10.10.89.8"
```

My gunicorn service is working properly and `nginx.conf` is also working properly with no errors.

All permissions have been granted to myproject directory
Still I am getting a *502 Bad Gateway* error.

Please let me know if any additional information needed

Comment: Does your `nginx` user has access to `/root/` directory where you've placed your `.sock`? I think there might be permission problem, at least it's bad idea to keep such things in restricted `/root/` directory.

Comment: @user973254 yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are creating the Socket file in different location and pointing the nginx to different location. Your socket file is created at
`/run/gunicorn.sock` as you can see from this command

```
ExecStart=/root/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock myproject.wsgi:application
```

and referring to it in different location(`/root/myproject/myproject.sock`) in nginx configuration as you can
see here

```
            proxy_pass http://unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock;
```

You can solve this in 2 ways

1. by changing gunicorn conf from

```
ExecStart=/root/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock myproject.wsgi:application
```

to

```
ExecStart=/root/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
```

2. By changing nginx conf  from

```
            proxy_pass http://unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock;
```

to

```
            proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
```

I recommend using the first approach

Restart both gunicorn and nginx after these changes

Comment: First solution didn't work but second one made project work properly.

Comment: Can you help me? i posted the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72434658/502-bad-gateway-nginx-1-18-0-ubuntu-django-nginx-gunicorn