# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) DJANGO - NGINX - GUNICORN

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I deleted the clinicsite file and then restored it. I restart gunicorn and nginx and the error came up

And my project have this structure:

[image]

gunicorn.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=sudo
WorkingDirectory=/root/myprojectdir
ExecStart=/root/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
      --access-logfile - \
      --workers 3 \
      --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
      clinicsite.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Error running manage.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
main()
File "manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 427, in run_from_argv
connections.close_all()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in close_all
for alias in self:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
return iter(self.settings)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in settings
self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/root/myprojectdir/clinicsite/settings.py", line 15, in <module>
import dj_database_url
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dj_database_url'
```

This is the error when running the manage.py file
nginx status shows active but gunicorn "Failed to start gunicorn daemon." Gives a fault

Do I need to share other files?

Comment: When you run `python manage.py runserver` on the server in the project directory then what message do you get?

Comment: Yes I am getting an error. I shared the error @AbhinavDev

Comment: run `pip install dj-database-url` after activating the virtual environment and then try running the python manage.py runserver